# Java enum - best practice to access enum ? direct access or using valueOf()?

Tags: java, enums

Let's say I have a simple enum:

```
public enum Status {
  ACTIVE("A", "Active Account"),
  INACTIVE("I", "Inactive Account");

  private String code;
  private String description;

  Status(String code, String description) {
    this.code = code;
    this.description = description;
  }

  public String getDescription() {
    return description;
  }
}
```

and that's 2 options to get the description, both returning the same result

```
 1. Status.ACTIVE.getDescription()
 2. Status.valueOf("ACTIVE").getDescription()
```

I used to do it with option 1 because I personally think that

```
1. More straight forward
2. Reduce typo compares to option 2
3. Any changes to enum will immediately get error in IDE or compile error instead of runtime error
```

but I wish to know is there any benefits using option 2? And what is the best practice to access the enum ?

Comment: Your reasoning is perfectly fine.  There are no benefits to using option 2 unless you have an _unknown_ string.

Comment: If you change the name of an enum constant: with usage 1 you get an error at compile time;  with usage 2 you get an error at run time.  Therefore, usage 1 is better.

Comment: The first approach, `Status.Active.getDescription()` is it provides compiler protection, as you're not relying on typing the string correctly.  It also avoids issues if the enum is renamed and, if you're using a decent IDE, you get auto complete.  Using `valueOf` is really meant to allow you to "load" a enum when you doing things like parsing a file or http request of some kind

Comment: Have you considered `for (Status s : Status.values()) { System.out.println(s.getDescription()); }`? Also, typo at `Inactibe`. And by convention `enum` constants are written in ALL CAPS.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on a case by case basis. If you need to query that using some input string you need valueOf.

ValueOf is technically slower since it runs string matching subroutines, so unless you need that part, the first one is a direct reference call which the compiler interprets as direct memory slot value retrieval rather than a function which must be ran at runtime.